# disable: Scanning for kotlin annotations

Tags: kotlin

I try to mix Kotlin into my spring project, but it adds at least 10 seconds scanning pakcages to booting time.

Can I disable this behaviour? If I do, what's the side effects? Thanks.

Here is the extra log after I added Kotlin:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building webapp 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ webapp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:0.10.4:compile (compile) @ webapp ---
[info] Kotlin Compiler version 0.10.4
[info] Compiling Kotlin sources from [src/main/resources, src/main/java]
[info] Classes directory is /Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes
[debug] Removed target directory from compiler classpath (/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes)
[info] Classpath: src/main/resources:src/main/java:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.4/mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.6.1.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.4/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jade4j/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-jade4j-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/de/neuland-bfi/spring-jade4j/0.4.2/spring-jade4j-0.4.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/de/neuland-bfi/jade4j/0.4.2/jade4j-0.4.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-jexl/2.1.1/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.1.0/pegdown-1.1.0.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/parboiled-core-1.0.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.0.2/parboiled-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-util/3.3.1/asm-util-3.3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-analysis/3.3.1/asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.9/commons-compress-1.9.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/ning/async-http-client/1.9.3/async-http-client-1.9.3.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.9.5.Final/netty-3.9.5.Final.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.12.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.12.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.12.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.12.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session-data-redis/1.0.0.RC1/spring-session-data-redis-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.2/commons-pool2-2.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session/1.0.0.RC1/spring-session-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/2.5.2/jedis-2.5.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/paypal/sdk/rest-api-sdk/0.12.2/rest-api-sdk-0.12.2.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/paypal/sdk/paypal-core/1.6.6/paypal-core-1.6.6.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3/gson-2.3.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.14.8/lombok-1.14.8.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/0.10.4/kotlin-stdlib-0.10.4.jar:/Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-runtime/0.10.4/kotlin-runtime-0.10.4.jar
[info] Classes directory is /Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.4/mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.6.1.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.4/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jade4j/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-jade4j-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/de/neuland-bfi/spring-jade4j/0.4.2/spring-jade4j-0.4.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/de/neuland-bfi/jade4j/0.4.2/jade4j-0.4.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-jexl/2.1.1/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.1.0/pegdown-1.1.0.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.0.2/parboiled-core-1.0.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.0.2/parboiled-java-1.0.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-util/3.3.1/asm-util-3.3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/asm/asm-analysis/3.3.1/asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.9/commons-compress-1.9.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/ning/async-http-client/1.9.3/async-http-client-1.9.3.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.9.5.Final/netty-3.9.5.Final.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.12.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.12.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.12.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.12/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.12.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session-data-redis/1.0.0.RC1/spring-session-data-redis-1.0.0.RC1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.2/commons-pool2-2.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session/1.0.0.RC1/spring-session-1.0.0.RC1.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/2.5.2/jedis-2.5.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/paypal/sdk/rest-api-sdk/0.12.2/rest-api-sdk-0.12.2.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/paypal/sdk/paypal-core/1.6.6/paypal-core-1.6.6.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3/gson-2.3.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.14.8/lombok-1.14.8.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/0.10.4/kotlin-stdlib-0.10.4.jar
[debug] Scanning for kotlin annotations in /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-runtime/0.10.4/kotlin-runtime-0.10.4.jar
[info] Using kotlin annotations from /Users/peisong/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-jdk-annotations/0.10.4/kotlin-jdk-annotations-0.10.4.jar
[debug] Using Kotlin home directory <no_path>
[debug] Configuring the compilation environment
[debug] Output:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/Kotlin.class
Sources:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/src/main/java/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/Audit.kt
[debug] Output:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/PayPackage$Audit$6a5fae39.class
Sources:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/src/main/java/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/Audit.kt
[debug] Output:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/target/classes/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/PayPackage.class
Sources:
/Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/src/main/java/io/vord/webapp/domain/pay/Audit.kt
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 59 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/peisong/Google Drive/java/vio/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ webapp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ webapp ---
```

Comment: Could you clarify: who is scanning what?

Comment: @AndreyBreslav Updated log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following configuration:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                <scanForAnnotations>false</scanForAnnotations>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: It seems that only when I start the server Kotlin compiler starts to compile source code, and this slows down the bootstrap. Is it possible to let Kotlin compiler compiles on the fly? And only recompile when changes are detected?

Comment: Incremental compilation as such is supported in the IDE only for now. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the exact toolchain you are using, so it's hard to tell if there are any other means that can accelerate compilation.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. I have enabled the experimental incremental compilation but each time when I restart the server even I have made no changes to *.kt files the Kotlin compiler still scan and compiles everything. Is it caused by maven plugin without checking the change status?

Comment: The log above is from Maven, not from the IDE, so yes, it's because Maven does not support incremental compilation